# Can we sort a column lexicographically in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to sort the **Value** column in the below table. If the values are the same, I want to sort the **Name** column lexicographically which means names - **Apple** and **Carrom** should shift one row up.

SELECT Id, Name, Value from tbl;

```
Id     Name          Value
--------------------------
1      Ant               1
2      Apron             3
3      Apple             3
4      Cat               1
5      Carrot            2
6      Carrom            2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

SELECT * FROM tbl
ORDER BY Name, Value;

You can select all Columns and order by Name and Value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @degik

Answer (score -1):

Select 'Ant' union all
Select 'Apron' union all
Select 'Apple' union all
Select 'Cat' union all
Select 'Carrot' union all
Select 'Carrom'
Select your column from yourtable
Order by YourColumn+replicate(char(255)